# How to open local machine exe file from server side script in c#? I Dont want ActiveXObect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How to open local machine .exe file from server side script in c#? I Dont want ActiveXObect.

Comment: server side script has no access to local machine ,its a browser security feature.you should not try execute exe from server.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Process.Start like the example below:

```
Process.Start("explorer.exe", linkPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Internet Explorer, you can use a javascript link but you must set security options on Intranet to allow this. I don't know of a way to do this with other browsers.

```
javascript:(new ActiveXObject('Shell.Application')).ShellExecute('shortcut.lnk');
```

Or

```
javascript:(new ActiveXObject('Shell.Application')).ShellExecute('pathtoprogram.exe');
```